# Rounding String values in Java

Tags: java, string

I want to round the decimal values of string.below is the example

String Result = "19292.5"

i want the output of result to round to 19292
In short i want to remove the ending .5 decimal value.

Comment: That's not rounding, that's flooring or truncating.

Comment: the value needs to be rounded UP to 19293.I dont want to suppress the decimal.For example if the string Result has 19292.5 it should roundUp to 19293.If it has 19292.0 or 19292 then pass AS IS no change req

Comment: yes you are rite and i agree with you its either flooring or truncating but now my requirement is to round UP the value

Comment: You should never have made it a String. You posted your arithmetic code below and you don't seem to have a problem using `Math.abs` there. So all you needed to do was use `Math.round` in the same way. **Don't do arithmetic in Strings**, because all you did was make it more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
String result = "19292.5";
int intValue = Double.valueOf(result).intValue();
```

If you need to round/floor a `double` value, you can use the `Math` class:

```
String result = "19292.5";
double rounded = Math.round(Double.valueOf(result));
double floored = Math.floor(Double.valueOf(result));
```

Comment: the value needs to be rounded UP to 19293.I dont want to suppress the decimal.For ex: if the string Result has 19292.5 it should roundUp to 19293.If it has 19292.0 or 19292 then pass AS IS no change required

Comment: @pawankumar, you have written something completely different in your question.

Comment: thanks kocko for the quick reply i will try and will let you know.

Comment: what is autoboxing?where should i use Double.parseInt inplace of Double.valueOf(result)?

Comment: @pawankumar Sorry, my bad, I meant `parseDouble`, not `parseInt`. [`Double.parseDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-) parses a String and returns a `double` primitive. [`Double.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) parses a String and returns a new `Double` object, so is a little slower. You should pretty much always use `parseDouble`. Likewise, instead of `(Float.valueOf(R1)).floatValue()` in your code, you should have `Float.parseFloat(R1)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
Result = Result.substring(0, Result.indexOf("."));
System.out.println(Result);
```

You could use substring to hack off everything after the ".".

Comment: If you are sure your String will contain a valid number, this would be the quickest method.  If you also want to ensure the String contains a valid number, the answer @kocko provided would be better as it would throw an exception if your String had invalid characters for a number.

Comment: I am new to this site.how should i assign points here.Sorry to ask this :)

Comment: This is my actual code  String R1= "19328";
  String R2= "19257";
  String Result;
  
  
  float a = (Float.valueOf(R1)).floatValue();
        
  float b = (Float.valueOf(R2)).floatValue();
  float c = a - b;
  float d = a + b;
  float e = (c/d)/2;
  float f = e * 100;
  if  (1> (Math.abs(f)))
  {
  float g = d/2;
  Result =""+g  ;
  }
  else if (a < b)
  Result =""+a ;
  else
  Result =""+b ;
  
//  String result = "19292.5";
  //int intValue = Double.valueOf(Result).intValue();
  
  Result = Result.substring(0, Result.indexOf("."));
  //return(Result);
  System.out.println(Result);

Comment: @pawankumar It's alright you can upvote that will assign 10 points (click up arrow by question) also you can accept this question as the right answer that will give 15 points.